# Output blank cell when source cell is empty

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a workbook with two spreadsheets - "Subscriptions CD" and "Subscriptions PD" - where I need to identify the new orders on the "Subscriptions CD" worksheet and mark these entries as "NEW" by comparing the data on the "Prior Day Orders". My formula appears to be working fine.  However, how can I hide the word "New" on rows with no data?

The current formula is:

```
=IF(B2=" ", " ",IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(B2*1,'Raw Data All Subscriptons PD'!A:A,1,0)),"NEW",IF(AND(VLOOKUP(B2*1,B:AA,26,FALSE)>1,VLOOKUP(B2*1,'Raw Data All Subscriptons PD'!A:Z,26,FALSE)=1),"NEW","")))
```

[image]

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Some diagrams of your data would help us understand your question. Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to catch the blanks by searching for a space, i.e., `" "`. A blank cell contains no space, so it won't match this. Instead, you should look for a blank with `""`, i.e., with no space between the quotes.

So, try this instead:

```
=IF(B2="", "",IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(B2*1,'Raw Data All Subscriptons PD'!A:A,1,0)),"NEW",IF(AND(VLOOKUP(B2*1,B:AA,26,FALSE)>1,VLOOKUP(B2*1,'Raw Data All Subscriptons PD'!A:Z,26,FALSE)=1),"NEW","")))
```